# menu bar buttons display correctly in IE but not FF - xhtml / css

Tags: firefox

I'm a bit of a n00b so please go easy.. I've searched for answers to my problem for some time now to no avail - so here it is:

I have a menu bar of buttons that should go right across the screen like so (pictured in IE):

![http://s957.photobucket.com/albums/ae55/tommyleinen/?albumview=grid][1]

In Firefox, the buttons appear to be displaced by the space below the text above them...

The easiest way to understand is to view the screenshots above.

I have tried adding a float attribute which has stopped the buttons from wrapping but the above problem still exists.

You can see the effect of playing with the Width % of the text above the buttons if this gives a clue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: u mean it displays wrong in IE and correctly in FF :).... also show us your code.

Comment: Yes, we need to see some code if we're going to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

discovered firebug which pointed to the padding being too much - didn't seem to let me put the code in the Qu box sorry about that. hopefully this may help other n00bs! Thanks for replying